# Why am I experiencing a "can't bind to x" error?

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if

I used this code in my component:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary "(click) ="toggle()" >Create</button>
```

and add this to app.component.html:

```
<app-table *ngif="showFirst"></app-table>
<app-form *ngif="!showFirst"></app-form>
```

I'm experiencing [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR44y.png):

> Can't bind to 'ngif' since it is not a known property of 'app-table'.

Comment: `*ngif` needs to be camelCase -`*ngIf`

Comment: how to do this i just added common module in app.modules.ts

Comment: but there is no effect

Comment: You don't need `CommonModule` in your main app module. Replace it with `BrowserModule`

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf

Answer (score 0):

fix the `*ngif` to be `*ngIf` because it's case-sensitive here because it's a directive not a html attribute